# Drivers for Windows 7 installation on USB HDD

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, usb, installation, drivers

Please explain which drivers can be used during Windows 7 installation for USB HDD in the known window with "Load Driver" link when there are the list of partitions and the message 
below: W7 cannot be installed on this drive ?

Warm Wishes

Comment: Do you have multiple hard drives on this computer? In that case what kind of drives (IDE, SATA)?

Comment: I have internal SATA disk and external USB HDD.

Answer (score 2):

Am I undertsanding it correctly that you wish to install Windows on a USB drive? Windows cannot be installed on a USB drive.  eSATA would work.  Possibly Firewire. While there may be a workaround there is an issue in the boot process that disconencts the USB device for a moment and naturally that casues the boot to fail.

Comment: Yes, I want to install Windows on a USB HDD. I know that Windows 7 installation doesn't want to install Windows 7 on a USB HDD.
It shows a message: W7 cannot be installed on this drive. BUT! it also shows a "Load Driver" link on this page.
I suppose I can load some driver(or drivers) via this link and Windows 7 installation will open the "NEXT" button.
At least how to list drivers which Windows 7 installation use here ?

Comment: The drivers are for storage controllers like RAID controllers or something too new to be supported by teh OS install disk.